# Custom message for an online chess game

Tags: online-chess, websites

I am trying to setup an online chess game that shows a custom message at the end of the match. The game would need to be setup as a human vs. the computer. Does anyone know of an online website that allows you to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked three of the major sites: Chess.com, Chess24.com, and Lichess.com, and none of them seem to support this.

This is close, but not just online, but The Internet Chess Club, aka ICC, lets you do this, but only using the newest client, "[ICC for Windows](https://www.chessclub.com/software-download/icc-for-windows)".

[Here are the instructions](https://support.chessclub.com/hc/en-us/articles/235680607--How-do-I-automatically-say-Thank-You-ICCforMac-Windows-).

And here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing that, I will check it out.